# Symmetrical power supply circuit

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

[image: Schematic]

I need  a symmetrical power supply for some op Amp applications. I did a research about symmetrical power supplies. And I've found that circuit on this site. It seems very easy but I try it on simulation software and it works. I was wondering that do you guys think it is suitable for basic op amp applications?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a virtual ground circuit.  And this one will not work in all applications - it's very limited in terms of the amount of current it can source or sink from the virtual ground.  For a simple audio amplifier running on a 9 volt battery, it's fine.  But for more demanding applications, it likely won't be sufficient.  A very simple improvement would be to add a single op-amp voltage follower (noninverting with unity gain) to act as a buffer on the GND line.  This would significantly improve the performance of the virtual ground.  I have used this technique on several different circuits myself, and it is quite effective.  Here is a page that covers several different methods for creating a virtual ground:

http://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html

Comment: Where are you getting 45 mA from?  That circuit would draw 45 uA.  The resistors are 100K ohms, not 100 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex said, your circuit has serious limitations about it's current because the current which will flow through GND will come from the source and go through the resistors. Therefore, the greater the current your circuit sinks, greater will be the voltage drop in those resistors. Then you will not have a stable reference. As he said, one way is to put a opamp as buffer in that point, so the reference will not sink much current (almost zero) and you can replicate this reference without that initial limitation.

Another way is to simply use two sources of 9V and connect them in series (GND from one to +9 of the other).

And finally, you can use single supply Op-amps that are very useful in those situations, like this one:

[LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf)

Comment: Single supply op-amps do not remove the necessity for a virtual ground, though.  They only let you work with lower supply voltages because they can swing their outputs closer to the supply rails.  You still need a virtual ground if you are using any inverting stages.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that. I think it all depends on your input signal. If you have a AC signal with DC level = 0, then of course you will need a dual supply or equivalent. But as long as your signal has a DC level and no negative voltage, you could threat your signal to match your DC level to your Vcc/2 value. Then you could use this as a input to a single supply opamp in reference do ground. Am I wrong?

Comment: That works as long as you don't have any inverting amplifier stages.  Inverting amplifier stages need a reference level to invert across.  The virtual ground would provide this.  And this has nothing to do with using single supply op amps.  If you use single supply op amps, it means you can run off of 5 volts or 3.3 volts and actually swing all the way from 0 to the rail voltage.  Also, if you have an AC signal, you can just run it through an RC high pass filter with a voltage divider for the R that will center the signal between the rails.

Comment: In some applications the virtual ground will be tied to high-impedance op amp inputs and nothing else.  In such cases deriving the virtual ground via resistors may be fine, since the current flowing into or out of it will always be essentially zero.  I would generally not use a ground symbol in such scenarios, however, since the normal assumption is that a ground symbol may safely sink or source a lot of current.